# Add counters to different rows by grouping

Tags: sql

A table with a number of rows that are grouped according to a field I want to be updated based on the row number of the updated number in a row.
Thank.

```
Item |  Number   
100      
150       
100      
150      
200
```

After the update

```
Item |  Number   
100      1    
150      1  
100      2
150      2 
200      1
```

Comment: A table has no built-in order. Does your table have a sequence or timestamp column as well?

Comment: Sure you know what you want, but not me. Can you reformulate et tell form where come the Number updated.

Comment: I think he mean that the 'item' column is the count of something. The 'number' column is the record number of the item. For example, the first time 100 is appear - number should be1, the second time - number should be 2 etc.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.